# loopback.io Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. confirm user

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, loopbackjs, supertest

I'm using mocha and supertest to create functional tests. Below is a copy of the test.

```
it("should verify user POST /api/User/confirm", function (done) {
    app.models.Users.findById(userId, function (err, usr) {
        json('get', '/api/user/confirm?uid=' + userId + '&token=' + usr.verificationToken)
        .expect(204,done);
    });
});
```

However this test returns :

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:689:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (/node_modules/loopback-explorer/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:134:22)
    at ServerResponse.header (/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:700:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:154:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:240:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:142:21)
    at defaultHandler (/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/rest-adapter.js:379:11)
    at restErrorHandler (/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/rest-adapter.js:348:14)
    at Layer.handle_error (/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:58:5)
    at trim_prefix (/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:300:13)
    at /node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
    at Function.proto.process_params (/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
    at next (/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
    at Layer.handle_error (/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:54:12)
    at trim_prefix (/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:300:13)
    at /node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
    at Function.proto.process_params (/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
    at Object.next (/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
    at Object. (/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:603:15)
    at Object. (/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31)
    at Object.immediate._onImmediate (timers.js:363:16)
    at processImmediate as _immediateCallback
```

I'm using the latest version of loopback at this point. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Well, although I don't see how this would produce the error you are seeing, you are performing a `GET` request when the `/api/user/confirm` endpoint only accepts `POST`... but again, I don't know why that would cause such an error.

Comment: I assumed it should be a POST however from my explorer the description is a GET

Answer (score 1):

This typically results from multiple uses of `res.send()` in the code.  I would check to see if this is the case.